# Android: Activity that displays a map image with zoom and drag?

Tags: android, image, zooming, drag

I need to display an image(a map), and allow users to drag and zoom(two finger pinch, or is multitouch control not support on some earlier versions?), also, when user clicks on an area on the map, information of that area is displayed. I wonder is there any standard way(such like imageview wrapped in an activity) of doing this, or do I have to create an activity that has imageview in it? I searched and read some of others questions/answers, found that WebView is a good way to display image, but I need to do some operations on the image(map) like I said, is it possible for WebView?

Thanks!

edit:
Is there anyway to do this, apart from femi's answer? Also, the 3rd party package in femi's answer has a bug report that pinch image view does not zoom, so it is actually no an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at http://code.google.com/p/android-pinch/ for ImageViews that offer some of what you need. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Sorry, I had a look at it, it has got Apache License 2.0, but I'm doing it for commercial product.

Comment: Unless you have some specific legal constraint, you can use Apache-licensed code in commercial software. This really shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Well, but is there anyway to do it via WebView, I mean can I detect clicks on an image(coordinate on the image) in WebView?

Comment: Ah, not that I'm aware of: perhaps with one of the canvas libraries you can do it, but I've not seen anyone who's done it before.